# How to get the MongoDB connection string?

Tags: mongodb

I've just installed and started MongoDB from official docs:  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/.

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew install mongodb-community@4.2
brew services start mongodb-community@4.2
```

How can I get URL / Connectionstring for the server?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your fresh standalone installation probably has no access control configured yet.
So the connection string is:

```
mongodb://localhost:27017
```

Otherwise, you have to provide username, password and auth source database in the connection string, e.g.

```
mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/?authSource=admin
```

Comment: I have one question, what does `authSource` field mean?

Comment: Name of the database where user credentials are stored.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#mongodb-urioption-urioption.authSource

Answer (score 6):

If you are already connected via shell/terminal, use `db.getMongo()` to return the connection string in the shell/terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Continuing from the same steps on the installation docs, there is a section for [Connect and Use MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#connect-and-use-mongodb), for connecting to the database from the shell.

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.4.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("....") }
MongoDB server version: 4.4.3
...
```

It should show the [connection string](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) it used (you can disregard the rest of the string after `?` unless it is `authSource`):

```
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
```